# Evento en JMenu de JavaSwing

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy haciendo un UI, estoy intentando ponerle un evento a un JMenu en un proyecto de JavaSwing, pero según he estado viendo, la única forma de aplicar eventos a un JMenuBar es aplicarlo a a los JMenuItems que están anidados dentro de los JMenu... Cosa que veo poco prática, es decir que poner un evento en una barra de menú tienes que a anidarlo sí o sí dentro de un JMenuItem...Simplemente quiero confirmar que es correcto esto o existe alguna posibilidad de ponerle el evento directamente al JMenu.
Saludos

Comment: Lo que ves *"poco práctico"* para algo simple, es lo que ayuda en casos complejos.

Answer (score 1):

si se puede, puedes aplicar el evento `MouseClicked`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por  ejemplo en el menu `File` hace lo mismo que el `JButton1`

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        creaf(jTextField1.getText());
        
    }                                        

    private void jMenu1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        creaf(jTextField1.getText());
    }
```